# autoFit font based on screen size in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, fonts

Kindly help us to resolve this issue.

I have many **Text** in **View** and text font size should calculate based on screen size.

I am using **minimumScaleFactor** to adjust font size to the **Text Width**. All the labels should adjust same size but its different size in each **Text**. You can find the difference in **SS**

[image]

pls find the code below

```
import SwiftUI

struct TrackLoanView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack{
                    ScrollView{
                        VStack{
                            HStack{
                                VStack{
                                    Text("KARTHI").fitSystemFont()
                                    Text("7502875893").fitSystemFont()
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                HStack{
                                    VStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "menucard")
                                        Text("REPORT").fitSystemFont()
                                    }
                                    VStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "menucard")
                                        Text("DOCUMENTS").fitSystemFont()
                                    }
                                    VStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "menucard")
                                        Text("CONTACT").fitSystemFont()
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }.padding()
                    }.background(Color.orange)
                }.background(Color.gray).padding(.all)
            }.navigationTitle("Track Loan")
        }
    }
}
public struct FitSystemFont: ViewModifier {
    public var lineLimit: Int?
    public var fontSize: CGFloat?
    public var minimumScaleFactor: CGFloat
    public var percentage: CGFloat

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            content
                .font(.system(size: min(min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height) * percentage, fontSize ?? CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)))
                .lineLimit(self.lineLimit)
                .minimumScaleFactor(self.minimumScaleFactor)
                .position(x: geometry.frame(in: .local).midX, y: geometry.frame(in: .local).midY)
        }
    }
}

public extension View {
    func fitSystemFont(lineLimit: Int? = nil, fontSize: CGFloat? = nil, minimumScaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.01, percentage: CGFloat = 1) -> ModifiedContent<Self, FitSystemFont> {
        return modifier(FitSystemFont(lineLimit: lineLimit, fontSize: fontSize, minimumScaleFactor: minimumScaleFactor, percentage: percentage))
    }
}
struct TrackLoanView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            TrackLoanView()
            
        }
    }
}
```

In **Android** all the **Text** remains same text **size**.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Do you want the text "KARTHI" and "7502875893" 
to be the same font size as in "REPORT" etc...? If so, you could try adding 
`.fitSystemFont()` to the `Image` as well. Alternatively, you 
could try "attaching" `.fitSystemFont()` ONLY to  
`ScrollView{  VStack{ ... }.fitSystemFont().padding()`. Apart from that, the text seems 
to fit well for me on ios 15 iPhone.

Comment: if i add to scrollview result not look good

Comment: no, not the  `ScrollView` the `VStack` inside, just before `.padding()`

Comment: Yes..Its working but when i am running in iPad its same as iPhone size..It should automatically calculate the font size and adjust based on the screen size.